# Meteor: How to create user without logging him in?

Tags: meteor, accounts

I want to create users by hand in my admin site. I find [Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser) seems to be the solution.

However, Accounts.createUser also logs in the newly created user, which is not what I want. I just want to create a user, not log in.

Is there any way to just create a user in Meteor?

Answer (score 5):

From the doc:

> On the client, this function logs in as the newly created user on
>   successful completion. On the server, it returns the newly created
>   user id.

This means that you could simply wrap your user creation into a method and run it only server side. That way you will keep your current logged-in user.